# Stuck with google admob sdk 7

Tags: ios, admob

I have implemented google admob sdk 6.12, ads were appearing , everything was  working perfectly, after few days google updated sdk 7, again i imported new sdk but this time i am unable to use `#import "GADInterstitial.h"` each time i get error #import "GADInterstitial.h" not found, imported all frameworks but no success and no ads are appearing if i use `@class GADInterstitial.h;` and use this code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
          [super viewDidLoad];
          self.interstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
          self.interstitial.adUnitID = Interstical_Unit_id;

          GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
          // Requests test ads on simulators.
          request.testDevices = @[ GAD_SIMULATOR_ID ];
          [self.interstitial loadRequest:request];
        }
 - (void)gameOver {
      if ([self.interstitial isReady]) {
        [self.interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];
      }
      // Rest of game over logic goes here.
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Admob SDK - iOS -File not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28572343/admob-sdk-ios-file-not-found)

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to import headers anymore, just use this and go

```
@import GoogleMobileAds
```

Also you don't need to link other frameworks or add the -ObjC to your linker flags.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this issue myself after upgrading. Use this instead:

```
#import <GoogleMobileAds/GADInterstitial.h>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you add GoogleMobileAdsSdkiOS-7.0.0 folder in your app, you have to replace your #import row with the following:

```
#import <GoogleMobileAds/GADBannerView.h>
```

I had the same issue.