# Admob SDK - iOS -File not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob

I have installed Google Analytics and Google AdMob SDK in my iOS project using Cocoapods. I have implemented both the functionalities in my app and everything looked okay for a week. Then suddenly, when I compiled the app, I received this error message:

```
"GADBannerView.h file not found". in "#import GADBannerView.h"
```

But I was able to see the header `GADBannerView.h` in my project under Pods target.

I did some research and found this error can happen due to `SEARCH PATH` in `BUILD SETTINGS`. Many faced similar issues when they moved the project from one machine to another machine but I didn't do that. So, instead of investigating on `SEARCH PATH`, I removed my `GADBanner` implementation from my project and commented line  `#import GADBannerView.h` and my project compiled successfully.

I don't quite understand why the Google Analytics SDK is getting compiled successfully while AdMob is throwing a compilation error. I even did a pod update and still received the same error.

The `SEARCH PATHS` in my target is `$(inherited)` and `ALWAYS SEARCH USER PATH` is set to `No`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Starting at AdMob 7.0, AdMob has made the SDK a framework. Import it like so:

```
#import <GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds.h>
```

Answer (score 3):

Go to:  --> **Build Settings** -->  **Apple LLVM 7.1 - Language - Modules** --> **Enable Modules (C and Objective-C)** --> set it to **Yes**.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Google Ads Developer Blog](http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.tw/2015/02/announcing-version-700-of-google-mobile.html) we need to use:

`@import GoogleMobileAds;`

If you have a problem with the `@import` syntax you need to modify your project build settings. Search for **Modules** and set **Enable Modules** to **YES**.

Answer (score -1):

First one is issue of latest SDK will not be used for Admob.
second is issue of Xcode 7.0 and you can try in Xcode xcode below 7 for till date,