# "GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds.h" file not found error

Tags: ios, admob

Recently I tried to update admob SDK(iOS) to the latest version(7.0.0)

I have trouble importing the framework.
[image]

It keeps giving me this error `"GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds.h" file not found`

I removed the old admob sdk and imported the framework manually.

[image]

I've tried

- restart xcode
- cleaning the project (command + shift + k)
- remove the framework and add it again

No luck, any ideas to solve this? thanks.

Comment: try once delete the framework and add again once

Comment: I've tried that, still giving me that error.

Comment: try this link https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-plugins/issues/68

Comment: possible duplicate of [Admob SDK - iOS -File not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28572343/admob-sdk-ios-file-not-found)

Comment: not yet, I'm using the old sdk for now

Answer (score 11):

Answer is to change the 'Framework Search Paths' build setting to the folder where your 'GoogleMobileAds.framework' is located.

Full steps I did to solve:

- Remove references to the framework from project navigator
- Click on your project in the project navigator, then on your project under 'TARGETS', then click 'Build Phases'
- Expand 'Link Binary With Libraries'
- Select 'GoogleMobileAds.framework' and click the '-' (if it's there)
- Click the '+'
- Click 'Add Other...', find and select 'GoogleMobileAds.framework' and click 'Open'
- The google ads framework should now be in the list
- Click 'Build Settings'
- Change 'Framework Search Paths' to the folder where your 'GoogleMobileAds.framework' is located
- Clean and re-build project

Comment: The key is adding the path in the Framework Search Paths .. thanks.

Comment: If you also don’t have 'GoogleMobileAds.framework' like mine, you can download it here: https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/download

Comment: There are a lot folders in the new admob framework. So please add recursive search to your framework search path.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on framework --> show in finder --> Delete framework from that place.--> go to the project and see at your framework place , its in red color .

Again right click on that and delete it. Again run project and save project . i know the build not successful.

Again add the framework and then run before that clean your project.

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode Settings, change below settings

```
Enable Modules (C and Objective-C)   YES
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

don't drag framework in your project..
just only copy past in your project folder and add files TO in your project..

i think it'[image]s 100% working.

Comment: Hello @Ankit, you suggest to not add framework and only add header files right

Answer (score 1):

**This is the Solution**

```
 #1 Open Terminal install Cocoapods -> $ sudo gem install cocoapods
 #2 Open Terminal and Enter Path of Your Directory -> cd desktop/gamebuild
 #3 Enter this on Terminal -> Pod Init
 #4 Go To Directory Paste This Line in Podfile -> pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
 #5 Close File and Enter this on Terminal-> Pod install
```

Answer (score 1):

After a days of web scraping i found a solution..You can follow the guide on the google ad mob official page.I have added the link...
https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start#cocoapods

Answer (score 1):

After several tries, I've finally managed to build my app (from a **Unity project**).
It took several steps from different answers here, so I'm posting the detailed steps of what I did.
*(I also want to practice formatting skills here in SO. lol)*

**Overview:**
The goal is to install admob cocoapod then set the FrameWork paths.
Yes, these have already been mentioned above but they come from different answers which was a bit confusing for me.

**Steps:**

1. Close Xcode if you have it running.
2. Open a Terminal window and enter the following:

   ```
   sudo gem install cocoapods
   ```

   This will install cocoapods
3. In the same Terminal, cd to your Xcode project directory:

   ```
   cd Documents/MyGitHub/MyNiceApp
   ```
4. Enter the following:

   ```
   pod init
   ```

   This will create a pod file in the project directory
5. Open the pod file in a text editor and do the following:

   - Uncomment the line for the platform (update the values if necessary)
   - In the section for Pods, add `pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '7.26.0'`
   - You can specify a version or leave it out to get the latest, like this: `pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'`
   - The File should look something like this:

```
        # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
        platform :ios, '9.0'
        
        target 'MyNiceApp-iPhone' do
          # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
          use_frameworks!
        
          # Pods for MyNiceApp-iPhone
          pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '7.26.0'
        
          target 'MyNiceApp-iPhone Tests' do
            inherit! :search_paths
            # Pods for testing
          end
        
        end
```

6. Back in the Terminal window where you cd'ed to your Xcode project, enter the following:

   ```
   pod install --repo-update
   ```

   This will install the admob framework and save it in your Xcode project directory
7. Open Xcode with your project or workspace
8. In Project Explorer, look for Pods > ... > GoogleMobileAds.framework

   Copy the Full Path from the properties, it would look something like this:

   ```
   /Users/mickeymicks/Documents/MyGitHub/MyNiceApp/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework
   ```

   Note: the path contains the "GoogleMobileAds.framework" at the end
9. Open Build Settings for your TARGETS

   Look for Framework Search Paths, double-click then add a new row for it.

   Paste the path you just copied.
10. Clean the project then Build.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same error. It was fixed really easy: I needed to open the `.xcworkspace` file instead of `.xcodeproj`.

Also did install pods beforehand but not sure if it contributes to the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they have some specific dependences and must be added to folder where is located .xcodeproj

[image: smth like this]

this is actual for **modul** import and without pods: `@import GoogleMobileAds;`

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to put the `GoogleMobileAds.framework\Versions\A\Headers`folder to `GoogleMobileAds.framework` folder and it worked for me.

[image: Then, in framework you can see]

---

Note:
 You **must delete `Header` file first**. It's already here in `GoogleMobileAds.framework` folder.
And use`GoogleMobileAds.framework\Versions\A\GoogleMobileAds` replace `GoogleMobileAds.framework\GoogleMobileAds`

Answer (score 0):

I am manually dragging the AdMob SDK into my project and was getting this error. Ultimately what worked was I dragged the SDK files into my projects folder on the computer (for me it was: Users/aaronfrom/documents/projectname) when asked to replace files I said yes. It then worked. I think that this is where my framework search path was directed towares and I needed to update the files in the project folder on my computer, it had nothing to do with settings in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have `google_mobile_ads.framework` in the Frameworks section in the General tab of your project target settings.

If not add the framework with the '+' button. It works for my case

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:
#import <GoogleMobileAds/GADInterstitialDelegate.h>

Comment: - This doesn't help because i need to use admob in my project.

Comment: I am not able to #import <GoogleMobileAds/GADInterstitialDelegate.h> is not found error.