# How I fix a "GADInsterstitial.h" file not found... but it is in my list?

Tags: ios, xcode, admob

I am having trouble installing a Interstitial ad into my Xcode project. I have download Google Ad Mob 7.0.0 and have continued with the instructions to implement an interstitial ad. [link](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/ios/interstitial)

When I go to `#import "GADInterstitial.h"` I am getting an error that the file not found. However, as seen in the picture attached the file is there as I added the files to the project. How do I correct this?

[image]

Comment: Do you have multiple targets?  If so, then it may be included in one but not the other ??

Comment: Hello @Stephan Rao did it worked

Comment: Yes. Earl's solution worked for me. My latest app I used the new 7.1 framework and as mob integrated seamlessly

Comment: possible duplicate of [Admob SDK - iOS -File not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28572343/admob-sdk-ios-file-not-found)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to reference the framework.

`#import <GoogleMobileAds/GADInterstitial.h>`

And if you are using modules ( @import GoogleMobileAds ) as is visible on the top, you should not need this particular import line for interstitial at all.

Comment: There's an error: it should be GoogleMobileAds and not GoogleMobileAdds.