# Update AdMob SDK from v6.12.2 to v7.8.1

Tags: ios, admob

I got a old project with admob sdk version 6.12.2 and I need to update the sdk.

from where to start ?

1) I try to delete the old folder of version 6.12.2 and after that install    admob cocapods and I got 18 linker errors.

2) I try to download the new sdk framework and replace it with the old and still have a errors.

- Warning: Multiple build commands for output file
- Undefined symbols for architecture arm64
- linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

what I do wrong ?

Comment: This is at least one of your issues: [Admob SDK - iOS -File not found](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28586662/2108547)

Comment: Also, 7.9.0 is the newest version of AdMob at the moment: [Google Mobile Ads SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/download)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by change this from no to yes !

[image]

Comment: awesome, i have no idea about this options,
Thanks